# how can i make crystal reports with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i wanna to create reports to print automatically  with laravel 
i tried this package

```
 barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('welcome');
        $output = $pdf->output();

        return new Response($output, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' =>  'inline; filename="dadsad.pdf"',
]);
```